# trace_call method for Fantom Opera

Tags: ethereum, web3js, evm, fantom

trace_call is a quite useful method for simulating transactions on blockchain:
https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/trace_call

But for some reason, all node providers support it only on Ethereum Mainnet and Polygon, rarely on Arbitrum and BSC. I wonder if there is a way to achieve the same for Fantom Opera and other EVM-compatible chains?
And if it's impossible, maybe there are other ways for transaction simulations?

Answer (score 1):

- With public blockchain technologies, you do not have vendor lock in and you can always achieve your goal regardless of what private companies tell you
- You can always run your own your own node with necessary tracing APIs enabled
- Running a node might need a beefy server costing hundreds of dollars per month to run
- If third party service providers do not support Fantom it is usually a sign there is no demand for this service